# Let WPF UserControl delete itself and Data-Object which is bound to it?

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls

I've placed in my MainWindow a StackPanel, which gets dynamically on runtime new UserControls (the UserControl is a row of TextBoxes and a button named "Delete").
This is about how I create the UserControls:

```
PersonObject p = new PersonObject;
List.Add(p);

UserControlLine usrCtrlLine = new UserControlLine();
usrCtrlLine.DataContext = p;

StackPanel.Children.Add(usrCtrlLine);
```

Now the UserControl contains Textboxes like this:
    TextBox TextWrapping="Wrap" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Path=Firstname, Mode=TwoWay}"

My questions are, how can I let the UserControl
- Remove itself from the StackPanel ("get deleted")
- Delete the PersonObject p which is bound to it?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand what you're trying to do here... You want to display a list of persons in the StackPanel ? You should use a ItemsControl, define its ItemsPanel as a StackPanel, and its ItemTemplate as a UserControlLine :

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding ListOfPersons}">
  <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
      <StackPanel IsItemsHost="True"/>
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
  </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
  <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <my:UserControlLine/>
    </DataTemplate>
  </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

To delete an item, you just remove it from the collection of persons, and the associated UserControlLine will also be removed from the ItemsControl (the collection should be an ObservableCollection)

Comment: Thanks for this Input! I googled some more with your keywords and found nice examples here: http://www.galasoft.ch/mydotnet/articles/article-2007041201.aspx